# How to Plot a Heatmap in ggplot with "staggered" points

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to graphically represent "heat" data for each of these points, , i.e. a univariate integer for each position.

The image is:

[image]

I don't have the data yet but I will have it like this where, agreed with the data acquirer, I staggered the positions on the x-axis to help me know spatially where I am looking at (where x and y are effectively co-oordinates T is the temp).

```
x   y   T
1   1   5
3   1   5
5   1   6
7   1   5
9   1   6
11  1   7
2   2   7
4   2   5
6   2   4
8   2   5
10  2   6
1   3   7
3   3   8
5   3   8
7   3   7
9   3   8
11  3   9
2   4   9
4   4   13
6   4   13
8   4   9
10  4   9
```

How can I best visually represent this heat map using ggplot (or a similar tool), please? I was just going to have boxes with blank spaces (as, for example, (1,2) doesn't exist) but the project team doesn't want that!

I don't care if the points are round, square/rectangle is fine.

Thanks in advance and hopefully my question was clear.

Comment: If the project team doesn't want blank spaces, what exactly do you want? Please detail the desired output so that the question can be answered. What are the specific requirements?

Comment: In the image, because the vessels are round, they are naturally staggered when stacked, so I want to represent that staggered position. I have data points for every position (not just the marked ones, apologies if that was confusing)

Comment: But how would the plot know which values are missing versus which values don't exist? What's the "range" of x and y?

Comment: There will be a measurement for each vial. So I will have x from 1 to 17 and y from 1 through 19. There may be the odd missing (or outlier) that I may remove but I should have all the data for the whole stack of vials.

Comment: If I plot them as a heatmap with the (x.y) that I have, I end up with a checkerboard of missing / heat data and I want to avoid that (at the team's request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would update @TTNK's answer to use round points, like your barrels, and to fix the coordinates to match circular packing, not squares.

```
  ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = Temp)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 21, stroke = 3) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.25,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:11, expand = c(0.25,0)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = tan(pi/3)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

While this gets you closer to your schematic, you have to fiddle with the `size =` and `stroke =` arguments to get your barrels just touching. If you want that to be automatic and at the right aspect ratio, but don't care as much about roundness, go with `geom_hex`:

```
  ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = Temp)) +
  geom_hex(stat = "identity", colour = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.25,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:11, expand = c(0.25,0)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = tan(pi/3)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Kudos for `coord_fixed(ratio = tan(pi/3))` . Definitely stashing that one away for future use!

I thought my way halfway there but my trig was too rusty. :)

Comment: @TTNK, I always have to double check by drawing a triangle to use the Pythagorean theorem and get the actual number.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this? Using the `geom_point` function from `package::ggplot2` (included in `tidyverse`, with an oversized glyph:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generating a data frame with alternating odds and evens
# Probably overwrought but makes the example cleaner

> df <- data.frame(x = rep(c(seq(1, 11, by = 2), seq(2, 10, by = 2)), 2), 
                 y = rep(1:4, times = c(6, 5, 6, 5)), 
                 'T' = sample(5:13, 22, replace = TRUE))

> head(df, 10)
    x y  T
1   1 1 10
2   3 1 12
3   5 1  8
4   7 1 10
5   9 1 12
6  11 1 12
7   2 2  9
8   4 2  9
9   6 2  6
10  8 2 10

> df %>% ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = T), size = 20, shape = 23) + 
  ylim(0, 5) + 
  xlim(0, 12) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]